# The page is not redirecting properly using header in php

Tags: php, facebook, loops, redirect, infinite

I don't know what is problem in the header location part,but there is some error due to which page gets infinite redirecting and stops after sometime.Here is my code,when i select a pic so that it should redirect to the facebook make cover or make profile page,but instead it keeps redirecting with a loop.

```
<?php
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook api library

######### edit details ##########
$appId = ''; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = ''; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/testing/process.php';  //return url (url to script)
$homeurl = 'http://www.mysite.com/testing';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,user_photos';  //Required facebook permissions
##################################



$GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page
$PicLocation ='';

/*
Users do not need to know original location of image.
I think it's better to get image location from database using ID.
for demo here i'am using PHP switch.
*/
switch($GetPicId)
{
case 1:
    $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover1.jpg';
    break;
case 2:
    $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover2.jpg';
    break;
case 3:
    $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover3.jpg';
    break;
default:
    header('Location: ' . $homeurl);
    break;
}

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $appId,
'secret' => $appSecret,
'fileUpload' => true,
'cookie' => true
));

//get user
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

//variables we are going to post to facebook
$msg_body = array(
'access_token' => $access_token,
'message' => 'I liked this pic from '. $homeurl .' it is perfect for my cover photo.',
'source' => '@'.realpath($PicLocation)
);

if ($fbuser){ //user is logged in to facebook, post our image
try {
$uploadPhoto = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $msg_body );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //output any error
}
}else{
$loginUrl =   $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'return_url'=>$return_url));
header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}

if($uploadPhoto)
{
/*
image is posted in user facebook account, but still we need to send user to facebook
so s/he can set cover or profile picture!
*/

//Get url of the picture just uploaded in user facebook account
$jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$uploadPhoto["id"]."&?access_token=".$access_token;
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

/*
We can not set facebook cover or profile picture automatically yet,
So, the trick is to post picture into user facebook account first
and then redirect them to a facebook profile page where they just have to click a button to set it.
*/
echo '<html><head><title>Update Image</title>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
echo '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
echo '</head><body>';
echo '<div align="center" class="fbpicwrapper">';
echo '<h1>Image is sent to your facebook account!</h1>';
echo '<div class="fbpic_desc">Click on desired button you want to do with this image!</div>';
echo '<div class="option_img"><img src="'.$json_output->source.'" /></div>';

/*
Links (buttons) below will send user to facebook page,
where they just need to crop or correct propertion of image and hit apply button.
*/
echo '<a class="button" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover='.$uploadPhoto["id"].'">Make Your Profile Cover</a>';
echo '<a class="button" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$uploadPhoto["id"].'&type=1&makeprofile=1&makeuserprofile=1">Make Your Profile Picture</a>';
echo '<a class="button" href="'.$homeurl.'">Back to main Page.</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</body></html>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any `echo` or any whitespaces printed to output before you're using the `header(Location...)` redirect. After you're already started printing to output the redirect won't work.

The way to do it is to save to string everything you want to print in case there's no redirect and print it to screen only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `header` method in 2 line that can be run by some true conditions in 2 time. It can makes a loop.

If `switch` not match any case and also `$fbuser` equals to `false` simultaneously.

First `header` method:

```
default:
    header('Location: ' . $homeurl);
    exit(); //added
    break;
```

Other `header` method:

```
if ($fbuser){ 
    //user is logged in to facebook, post our image
}
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $fbPermissions, 'return_url' => $return_url));
    header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
    exit(); //added
```

Comment: So,which header method i should remove to make it work properly?

Comment: @RohanMishra add `exit();` after each `header` methods to make sure running process of code not continue so and try.

Comment: Or maybe you have the issue calling Facebook API? this can make a loop perhaps.

Comment: what issue may exist? When i ran the app,,1st time it took the permissions after login and then it kept redirecting,now am just logging in and it keeps redirecting

Comment: So, It's hard to understanding. I suggest that `var_dump()` your variables and `die()` the page to debug.

Comment: did u visit the website?Then i think u will get to know the problem.

Comment: Yee, as I said, It's hard to understanding